# Is tantra sadhana always restricted?

Tags: mantras, tantra

I will classify mantras into two types as follows:

1) Mantras with no restrictions and with no negative effects;

2) Mantras with restrictions and hence having negative effects when recited in improper way or improper manner;

Does sadhana mantras in tantra texts always fall under second category?

Comment: I would not classify mantras this way.

Comment: No ..  all Mantras have restrictions imposed upon them. These restrictions are either naturally present or imposed later to prevent the misuse of the Mantras.

Comment: @Rickross *Sree Ram* mantra also has restriction?

Comment: There are many Rama mantras and all of them hv separate rules of chanting so which one are u talking about? Or are u talking about chanting just this "Sri Rama"? @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: Chanting just "Sri Rama" @Rickross

Comment: Ok then that is not exactly a Mantra.. It is Nama Japa.. Probably no restrictions are there on that.. But u must also be knowing the story of Narada initiating Valmiki Rishi into Rama nama japa .. @hanugm

Comment: @Rickross Then all existing mantras fall under second category 2 only. No mantra is meant to use anywhere anytime by anyone?

Comment: Only after initiation one can always chant the Guru given mantra.. otherwise there are certain restrictions on every mantra.. @hanugm Also it is not that it will create negative effects but there won't be any good results too.. So, after initiation and after knowing all the rules one shd chant  mantras.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87478/discussion-between-hanugm-and-rickross).